# Iterate a JSON map and get Key Value Pairs in Ballerina

Tags: json, iteration, ballerina

I have the following JSON:

```ballerina
json envs = {
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "password",
    "key": "key1"
};
```

Is there a way to iterate through this JSON map and get key-value pairs in Ballerina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can narrow the type to a `map<json>` and then use a function from the `ballerina/lang.map` langlib or any other operation (e.g., iterating with `foreach`) available on maps. Check the below code:

```ballerina
public function main() returns error? {
    // Similar to a cast, but returns an error instead of
    // panicking if incompatible.
    map<json> envsMap = check envs.ensureType();

    foreach [string, json] [key, value] in envsMap.entries() {
        // Handle the values here.
    }
}
```